# Re-number the steps shown on the "asking a good question" modal

Tags: feature-request, design, asking-questions

I noticed this behaviour yesterday when posting a question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com):

[image]

The steps listed on the banner normally shown on the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page when you ask your first question... aren't really well numbered. Shouldn't it look like this:

[image]

Since researching the problem/report/request is certainly encouraged when asking a question?  Also, the line "*Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn't been answered*" really needs to say, "*To make sure your question hasn't **already** been answered*".  That just makes me cross.  No new user wants to see that ;)

---

**EDIT**

A user said:

> I think that "Before your post..." is not numbered because that is somethin that is not done on the Ask page, while the numbered items are done in the Ask page.

Possibly, but searching for an answer beforehand definitely contributes to asking a good question, in the page or not. I intend this to be a help toward the correct way to engage with the site.

Comment: I think that "Before your post..." is not numbered because tha is somethin that is not done on the Ask page, while the numbered items are done in the Ask page

Comment: @Rubén I get your point, but searching for an answer beforehand definitely contributes to asking a good question, in the page or not. I intend this to be a help toward the correct way to engage with the site.

Comment: Also users should have a "doubt" before searching and before that they should do other  things... we will not list all of them on the modal , right?

Comment: @Rubén I don't think so.  As stated in the question title, a re-numbering of the items already listed, the most important ones, would be sufficient.

Comment: @Rubén also see [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357641/re-number-the-steps-shown-on-the-asking-a-good-question-modal/357668#comment1194939_357668).

Comment: I agree with zcoop98, including the suggestion using other way to highling instead of numbering the "Before you post..." part

Comment: Any list longer than 3 is too long for the average question-poster, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with this proposal as-is.

The dialogue reads (including the text for thoroughness):

> ## Asking a good question
>
> You're ready to ask your first question, and the community is here to help! To get you the best answers, we've provided some guidance:
>
> Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn't been answered.
>
> 1. Summarize the problem
> 2. Provide details and any research
> 3. When appropriate, describe what you've tried
>
> <sub>You'll find more tips in the sidebar.</sub>
>
> <kbd>Start writing</kbd> <kbd>Don't show this to me again</kbd>

As-is, the numbered steps pertain exclusively to the development of the actual written body of the post, of which duplicate finding does not, and I personally feel that this is structured as it should be.

While searching for duplicates is absolutely an important step in deciding to post a question, *especially* for first-posters, it is not a step in the actual composition of that question.

I think the inclusion of the tip above the numbered list is sufficient, and fits best with the current structure of the content in the modal.

---

To be fair, extra highlighting of that *"Before you post..."* sentence seems like it could be a great change though. I agree it's potentially easy to gloss over, largely because it isn't part of the numbered list, which is the most eye-catching detail of the modal. Something like emboldening or italicizing that tip might be enough.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to disagree with your disagreement.  We do want users to search the site before posting, and that does contribute to asking a good question, because it helps other users.  It might not help *writing* the actual question, but you should always make the first thing you want done Step 1, especially with a numbered list.